# Wordpress Website Issues

Tags: html, wordpress, xampp, hosting

I created my wordpress site, then I transferred all my files and sql over to a host using hostgator.com. In my pc, the website was located in xampp\htdocs\mywebsite.  I transferred all the files inside of \mywebsite to  public_html using a ftp client, and the website worked, however it just looked like a basic html website, no images or anything like it should be. I then placed all the files inside of a folder called mywebsite inside of public_html, and then it worked fine.  I'm guessing I need to reconfigure some files in order to get it to work from just mywebsite.com, instead of mywebsite.com/mywebsite.

The only files I have modified so far is obviously the wp-config.  I apologize for this lengthy question, and if this was hard to understand, but I would really appreciate any help given. Any help is extremely appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the wordpress codex regarding moving your website: http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

You are going to need to use [this](http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) search and replace tool, which is also mentioned in the above link.

Also remember to change the links in Settings -> General in the wordpress dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider the Duplicator plug-in if you have control of both databases. It makes things pretty easy.

If you end up doing things the long way, make sure that the info in both wp-config files matches.